# LARAVEL Fatal Error Exception : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10489856 bytes)

Tags: laravel, memory-limit

i want to run this code

```
$late = Attendance::whereUserType(5)
         ->where('datetime_in', '!=', null)
         ->where(DB::connection('attendance')
         ->raw('DATE(created_at)'), date('Y-m-d'))
         ->orderBy('user_id')->get()->take(10);
```

but i got an error like in the title said. When i change the **memory_limit** to 512M, my browser is lag. I'm using 16K+ data for testing, is it ok ?? And what is the problem ??

Comment: Try to invert the way you search, change get()->take(10) to take(10) -> get()

Comment: @rikardo_paiva whoa it works! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to invert the way you search, changes **`get()->take(10)`** to **`take(10)-> get()`**

Comment: so how to call the data from blade ??

Answer (score 6):

Try to add this on top of the script

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

Your query could be timing out